# Divide a file based on pattern

Tags: json, bash, awk

I have a JSON output generated as part of a curl command and want to split resultant file based on a pattern:

### File content looks something like

```
{
"clusters" : [ {
"name" : "subject",
"version" : "XXX",
"services" : [ {
  "name" : "initiator",
  "config" : {
    "items" : [ {
      "name" : "enableSecurity",
      "value" : "true",
      "sensitive" : false
    }, {
      "name" : "service_config_suppression_server_count_validator",
      "value" : "true",
      "sensitive" : false
    } ]
  },
  "roles" : [ {
    "name" : "intiator-role1",
    "type" : "SERVER",
    "hostRef" : {
      "hostId" : "754389-8989db-8743ty"
    },
    "config" : {
      "items" : [ {
        "name" : "role_creds",
        "value" : "sdfujnvhdsg87909",
        "sensitive" : true
      }, {
        "name" : "serverId",
        "value" : "1",
        "sensitive" : false
      } ]
    },
    "roleConfigGroupRef" : {
      "roleConfigGroupName" : "initiator-group"
    }
  } ]
} ]
},
....bunch of lines in between
..........

 {
  "name" : "subject2",
  "version" : "XXX",
"services" : [ {
  "name" : "ingestor",
  "config" : {
    "items" : [ ]
  },
  "roles" : [ {
    "name" : "ingestor-role1",
    "type" : "service",
    "hostRef" : {
      "hostId" : "754389-8989db-8743ty"
    },
    "config" : {
      "items" : [ {
        "name" : "role_code",
        "value" : "sdfujnvhdsg67340",
        "sensitive" : true
      } ]
    },
    "roleConfigGroupRef" : {
      "roleConfigGroupName" : "ingestor-group"
    }
  } ]
  } ]
  }
  ]
  }
```

---

I want to split this file into different files whenever string "version":"XXX" repeats. So that generated file should have contents starting first two lines before the string until next string occurrence.

This is just an excerpt taken from a huge json file, in this data set I have kept only two string patterns hence expecting two files with below contents:

file 1 should have:

```
"clusters" : [ {
"name" : "subject",
"version" : "XXX",
"services" : [ {
  "name" : "initiator",
  "config" : {
    "items" : [ {
      "name" : "enableSecurity",
      "value" : "true",
      "sensitive" : false
    }, {
      "name" : "service_config_suppression_server_count_validator",
      "value" : "true",
      "sensitive" : false
    } ]
  },
  "roles" : [ {
    "name" : "intiator-role1",
    "type" : "SERVER",
    "hostRef" : {
      "hostId" : "754389-8989db-8743ty"
    },
    "config" : {
      "items" : [ {
        "name" : "role_creds",
        "value" : "sdfujnvhdsg87909",
        "sensitive" : true
      }, {
        "name" : "serverId",
        "value" : "1",
        "sensitive" : false
      } ]
    },
    "roleConfigGroupRef" : {
      "roleConfigGroupName" : "initiator-group"
    }
  } ]
} ]
},
....bunch of lines in between
..........
```

and file 2 should have

```
 {
  "name" : "subject2",
  "version" : "XXX",
"services" : [ {
  "name" : "ingestor",
  "config" : {
    "items" : [ ]
  },
  "roles" : [ {
    "name" : "ingestor-role1",
    "type" : "service",
    "hostRef" : {
      "hostId" : "754389-8989db-8743ty"
    },
    "config" : {
      "items" : [ {
        "name" : "role_code",
        "value" : "sdfujnvhdsg67340",
        "sensitive" : true
      } ]
    },
    "roleConfigGroupRef" : {
      "roleConfigGroupName" : "ingestor-group"
    }
  } ]
  } ]
  }
  ]
  }
```

Looking to achieve this via bash, awk preferably , thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want your input split every 27 lines right? If not then [edit] your question to explain how you want the input divided. Also provide what you have tried so far yourself.

Comment: The sample doesn't look like valid JSON. If you are not posting a representative sample, you should explain what you have elided.

Comment: Oooh, *"elided"`, good form...

Comment: @tripleee I have edited with correct data set as requested

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet in this case is to use `jq`. https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/

jq allows you to manipulate and query any JSON content.

**Updated:**

I edited your source JSON above so it's actually valid JSON, and these are the commands I used to get `jq` to give me each of the elements within the `clusters` array:

```
 jq '.["clusters"] | .[0]' test.json

 jq '.["clusters"] | .[1]' test.json
```

Of course, you can script this as you wish.  There's no need to search for the `version="XXX"` text, since they're all simply elements within the `clusters` array.

Comment: A proper answer would explain how to do the actual splitting in `jq`.

Comment: @tripleee Agreed. Updated the answer to show how the actual splitting would work with jq.

Comment: `jc -c '.clusters[]' test.json` would produce one cluster per line which you can then split with some standard Unix line-based utiltity like `split`.

Comment: thanks for sharing, can't use/install jq, need to be able to do it with awk, bash etc

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to split the file into a new file each time "version" repeats, starting and ending with 2 lines before "version", you can probably do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '
BEGIN {
    i = 0
}
{   
    prevLn2 = prevLn1
    prevLn1 = currentLn
    currentLn = $0

    if(currentLn ~ /^[ ]{0,}\"version\"/) {
        i++
    }

    if(i > 0) {
        print prevLn2 >> "file" i ".txt"
    }
}
'
```

This saves the 2 previous lines in variables prevLn1 and prevLn2, and for each line in the input checks if the current line matches the regular expression `^[ ]{0,}\"version\"` – meaning the start of the line, then zero or more spaces, and the literal text "version". If it matches, increase the variable i. Then append the second previous line to the file which is named with the variable i.

Save the code in a file e.g. `splitfile.sh`, and make it executable `chmod 755 splitfile.sh`.
Usage: `./splitfile.sh < jsonfile.txt` will generate the files file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt... in the same directory.

Comment: thanks for above, I tried for  ("version" : "XXX") but the script doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Cod_enthu The script is not supposed to return anything. It splits the input into several files as you requested. The generated files are located in the same directory as the script. Please clarify how you are executing the script and what your input is.